# regarding leading zero in integer value

Tags: java

I have below code

```
int a = 01111;
System.out.println("output1 = " + a);
System.out.println("output2 = " + Integer.toOctalString(1111));
```

and output is

> ```
> output1 = 585
> output2 = 2127
> ```

I was expecting output to be like below.

> ```
> output1 = 2127
> output2 = 2127
> ```

Why does it give `585` when I print direct int value ? I was expecting java to automatically convert value with leading zero to octal.

What is the relation between `01111` and `585`?

Comment: `585` is a decimal and `1111` is octal equivalent of `585`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Leading 0 signifies an octal number (base 8).

01111 (octal) is 1*8^3+1*8^2+1*8^1+1*8^0=585 (decimal)

`Integer.toOctalString(1111)` converts the decimal number 1111 to an octal String. 2127 octal (2*8^3+1*8^2+2*8^1+7*8^0) is 1111 decimal.

Comment: This is what the OP is expecting and not getting. Question is: Why he's not getting it? Or to be exact, why it differs from the other print statement.

Comment: @amit `Why does it give 585 when I print direct int value ?` Implies that he got 585 even though he didn't expect it.

Comment: @Eran My miss understanding was,I thought that when you take value with leading zero it is decimal and while printing jvm convert that decimal value to octal value...so I was thinking value 01111 was decimal and SOP should convert that to octal value 2127. but actually jvm implicitly consider  01111 as octal value because I have assigned it with leading zero.

Answer (score 4):

```
System.out.println("output2 = " +Integer.toOctalString(1111));
```

Is converting the decimal string `1111` to an octal string: `2127`.

The decimal value of the octal `1111`, is `585` - as expected, the result is expected, you don't get the same values because the two statements do different things.

A correct test will be:

```
System.out.println("output2 = " +Integer.toOctalString(a));
```

Which will give you, as expected, `1111`

Answer (score 0):

If a number literal starts with `0` it denotes the octal base. Similarly `0x` denotes hexadecimal base and `0b` the binary number.

So your

```
int a=01111;
```

.. is actually

```
8^3 + 8^2 + 8^1 + 8^0 = 
512 + 64 + 8 + 1 = 585
```

The `Integer.toOctalString(1111))` is actually a reverse function, i.e. the result is the octal number which is 1111 in decimal, which `2127` really is

```
2127(oct) = 2 × 8^3 + 1 × 8^2 + 2 × 8^1 + 7 × 8^0 = 1111(dec)
```